# NullPointerException Constructor

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

How does ist come that c and today is not visible in fetchingData() ?
I get a NullPointer-Exception when running the code in main-class :/
Thanks for any help!

```
public class InputData {

    Calendar c;
    Date today;

    String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;

    Double[][] hPrice;
    Double[][] qhPrice;
    Double[][] qhEua;
    Double[][] qhGas;
    Integer[][] qhTemperature;
    Integer[][] qhAirpressure;

    Date[][] qhDate; // may be useful some day
    Date[][] qhWeatherDate; // may be useful some day

    public InputData() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date today = new Date();
        today = c.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(today));
    }

    public void startFetching() {
        // +++ Access-Import EUA's +++
        Access aQuery = new Access();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        today = c.getTime();
        aQuery.eua(sdf.format(today));
```

Comment: where is the fetchingData() method??

Comment: Where is `fetchingData()`? How does your `main()` look like? How do you know it's `c` that throws the Exception? What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: sorry Its actually the startFetching()-Method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You save the objects in local variables and don't use the class members.
Change your code:

```
  public InputData() {
        this.c = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.today = new Date();
        today = c.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        System.out.println(sdf.format(today));
    }
```

Comment: ahhh I'm stupid. Sorry for bothering. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome. You can also mark my answer as solution;)